# How to update formset with new pk id?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset that I am rendering with the default `{{ formset }}`. The page does a post back to itself when the form is submitted.

The issue is when new instances are created, the fields containing the ids are still blank like `<input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden">`. So if I resubmit the form after it comes back, it ends up creating new instances instead of updating the newly-created instances. If I refresh the page then the fields contain the ids `<input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="18">`.

This is my controller function:

```
def main_categories (request):
    dict = {}
    FormSet = modelformset_factory (MainCategory, formset = MainCategoryFormSet, fields = ['name'], extra = 1, can_delete = True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FormSet (request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid ():
            with transaction.atomic ():
                formset.save ()
    else:
        formset = FormSet ()

    dict ['formset'] = formset
    return render (request, 'equipment/admin/main_categories.html', dict)
```

Comment: Doesn't clear for me, but if you update with more code (models, formset, urls, ...) or better link to project itself I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit previously submitted queryset, you must provide queryset into FormSet class. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)

Comment: I just reassigned a new FormSet instance to the variable after I saved it which sets the queryset to be the entire collection. Simple enough.